# Issue with tableadapter.insert

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am new for programming and trying to learn VB.net through youtube tutorials. so I tried to create separate forms for a "login" and "create new account".  The login seems to work fine.  However, the create account becomes difficult for me to successfully code it.  The main issue I have is with the "Insert" code. I created a "createnewaccount" form and connected a database to it. Then I write a code under "btnsave" so that when people create new account it will be saved to the database. This is where I keep getting issues. where it says "UsersPasswordsTableAdapter1.Insert" it underlines it all the time and the program wouldn't work.   Here are my codes. Any help would be helpful.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class CreateNewAccount

```
Private Sub CreateNewAccount_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.UsersPasswordsTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.UsersPasswordsDataSet1.UsersPasswords)

End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveNewAccount_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveNewAccount.Click
    LoginPage.UsersPasswordsTableAdapter1.Insert(Me.TextBox1.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text)
    LoginPage.UsersPasswordsTableAdapter1.Fill(LoginPage.UsersPasswordsDataSet1.UsersPasswords)
    MsgBox("Your Account has been saved successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""

End Sub

Private Sub btnBacktoLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBacktoLogin.Click
    Me.Hide()
    LoginPage.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You need to learn to diagnose errors. Start with the [Error List Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33df3b7a.aspx)